# wrong number of lifetime parameters: expected 1, found 0

Tags: rust

I'm having a really hard time fathoming pointers in Rust. This code won't compile because: `wrong number of lifetime parameters: expected 1, found 0 [E0107]`. What does that mean?

```
struct Planet<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    radius_km: i32,
    surface_area_km2: i64,
    orbital_period_days: i32,
    distance_from_sun: i64
}

fn mercury() -> Planet {
    Planet {
        name: "Mercury",
        radius_km: 2_440,
        surface_area_km2: 74_800_000,
        orbital_period_days: 88,
        distance_from_sun: 57_910_000
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mercury = Box::new(mercury());
    println!("{}",mercury.name)
}
```

Comment: Note that the error message *includes* the problem line and even contains a span (`^~~~`) that [helps show where the problem is](http://is.gd/poWU1h).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's saying that your definition for the struct includes a type parameter and, therefore, so must your function that creates one.

```
struct Planet<'a>{
    name : &'a str,
    radius_km: i32,
    surface_area_km2: i64,
    orbital_period_days: i32,
    distance_from_sun: i64
}

fn mercury<'a>()->Planet<'a>{
    Planet{
        name:"Mercudy",
        radius_km: 2_440,
        surface_area_km2: 74_800_000,
        orbital_period_days: 88,
        distance_from_sun: 57_910_000
    }
}

fn main(){
    let planet = mercury();
    println!("{}", planet.name)
}
```

Comment: While `'a` works, in this case you might as well pick `'static`, since the string lives for the entire lifetime of the program.

Comment: Personally, I'd have just made it String instead of &'whatever str, but that's not the question asked. Curious what the difference would be between the two options.

Comment: Between which two options? If you use String, then you'd allocate memory each time you call `mercury`, which isn't really needed here. If you stay with a lifetime parameter on `mercury`, then the *caller* of `mercury` decides what lifetime `'a` will be. This is fine, because the `'static` lifetime will always outlive it. Marking the return lifetime as `'static` just ends up being more flexible and useful for this case.